# Converting NSData to NSAttributedString in Swift

Tags: swift

I have this code working in Objective-C:

```
NSAttributedString* plainString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:self.entry.data options:@{} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

`self.entry` is a reference to a custom object with several properties. `data` is defined as

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData * data;
```

However, in swift, the following code generates an "**Extra argument 'data' in call**" error:

```
var plainString = NSAttributedString(data: self.entry.data, options: [], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)
```

I'm aware that the error is because the types don't match. The data parameter is expecting a NSData! but I'm not sure how to get to that point. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is misleading, the error is actually in the second argument:
an empty dictionary is denoted by `[:]`, not `[]`:

```
NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [:], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)
```

Alternatively, you can also pass `options: nil`.

Comment: That did the trick! Can't tell you how long I stared at that.